# Insert date into a SQL Server database in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, date

I want to insert a date into a database in Asp.net. I have a webpage where a title, date and news content is submitted. This should be written to a database and when the page is reloaded the page will contain the details including the date.

When I test this, I get the following error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Any ideas??

My aspx code is:

```
<div class="form-group alert alert-info">
    <asp:label runat="server" ID="lblNewsDetails">Please enter news details below</asp:label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:TextBox name="txtTitle" id="txtTitle" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" value="" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:TextBox name="txtDate" id="txtDate" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Today Date DD/MM/YYYh" value="" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:TextBox namee="txtNewscontent" name="txtNewscontent" id="txtNewscontent" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="News Content" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        <asp:button runat="server" text="Save" id="btnSend" OnClick="BtnSend_Click"/>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

My aspx.cs code is

```
protected void BtnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create a SQL Connection - get the connection string from the web.config
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    // define the SQL statement you wish to run - use @ placeholders to populate parameters
    string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO News (Title, DatePosted, NewsContent) Values (@Title, @DatePosted, @Newscontent);";

    // Set up the SQL Command
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection);

    // Populate the placeholders with parameter values
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", txtTitle.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatePosted", txtDate.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Newscontent", txtNewscontent.Text);

    // open a connection to the database 
    connection.Open();

    // Run the SQL statement against the database
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // NOTE! close the connection
    connection.Close();
}
```

The database table has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[News] 
(
    [Id]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title]       NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [DatePosted]  DATE           NOT NULL,
    [NewsContent] NTEXT          NOT NULL,
    [IsRead]      BIT            DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: What value you are entering in txtDate? You need to first convert that to datetime and then pass it to sqlparameter

Comment: You can't use the format "dd/MM/yyyy" if your SQL Server is configured to use American date format. The safest way of passing a date is to use ISO 8601 format, "yyyy-MM-dd".  Also, your placeholder text is a little weird: "Enter Today Date DD/MM/YYY**h**" h? You want the users to enter the hour after three digits of the year? ;)

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This will ensure the data type is date, rather than a string when it's passed to the db

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatePosted", Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text));
```